# Mouse Click curser effect throughout site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it would be cool to set a custom cursor click effect with jQuery. Something similar to Android Incredible 2 browser where it highlights click-able items in green when selected. Except mine would be the cursor with a box around it something like 1px width, very subtle, and it would kind of float/toggle until you point over a clickable item - and then it would kind of 'lock' in.

I've found something like this that was done that fired a bunch of squares on clicks, but I can't relocate where I found it - and it was a huge amount of JavaScript, is this possible with jQuery - and would this be a bad idea for the users experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to change cursor, and with JavaScript events you can change your cursor whenever you want. Here is an example:

```
<style>
  .cursor1 { cursor: pointer; }
  .cursor2 { cursor: url(myCur.cui); }
</style>

<script>
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  mydiv.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add("cursor2");
  }
  mydiv.onmouseup = function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove("cursor2");
  }
</script>

<div id="myDiv" class="cursor1"> Here is my text!! </div>
```

Also, you can use JQuery.